# How to redirect sitemap.xml used depending on the domain?Undo edits

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

How I can redirect sitemap.xml file access to different subfolders, if it can be reached from three different domains?

- domain1/sitemap.xml -> domain1/es/sitemap.xml
- domain2/sitemap.xml -> domain1/de/sitemap.xml
- domain3/sitemap.xml -> domain1/uk/sitemap.xml

domain1, domain2, and domain3 target to the same folder.

Is it possible? How can I do this? Should do it with PHP ?

PS: The server is a linux running apache, the web platform is a wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  Put it in your virtual host configuration, preferably; htaccess can work as well but hurts performance (and will require some tweaks to the rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
# domain1/sitemap.xml -> domain1/es/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ http://domain1.com/es/sitemap.xml [R=301,L]
# domain2/sitemap.xml -> domain1/de/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ http://domain1.com/de/sitemap.xml [R=301,L]
# domain3/sitemap.xml -> domain1/uk/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ http://domain1.com/uk/sitemap.xml [R=301,L]
```